# Sum up columns between two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have an application where students do three choices 1st, 2nd and 3rd from a list.

Table1 is the list they can choose from:

| id | day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday |
| 2 | Thusday |
| 3 | Wednesday |

Table2 is they fill in their choices:

| id | first_choice | second_choice | third_choice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 23456 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 34567 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 45678 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

What I'm struggling with is that I want to count choices per day and priority to get a list like this:

| id | first_choice | second_choice | third_choice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Thusday | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Wednesday | 1 | 1 | 2 |

```
SELECT a.day, count(b.first_choice), count(c.second_choice), count(d.third_choice) FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.first_choice LEFT JOIN table2 c ON a.id = c.second_choice LEFT JOIN table2 d ON a.id = d.third_choice GROUP BY a.day
```

But, by doing so I end up with this

| id | first_choice | second_choice | third_choice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Thusday | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Wednesday | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Could anyone help me with the query?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `INNER JOIN` and work it out with conditional `IF` statements:

```
SELECT  
    Table1.id, 
    Table1.day,
    COUNT(IF(Table2.first_choice=Table1.id, Table2.first_choice, NULL)) AS first_choice,
    COUNT(IF(Table2.second_choice=Table1.id, Table2.second_choice, NULL)) AS second_choice,
    COUNT(IF(Table2.third_choice=Table1.id, Table2.third_choice, NULL)) AS third_choice
FROM
    Table1
INNER JOIN 
    Table2
ON 
    Table1.id = Table2.first_choice 
OR 
    Table1.id = Table2.second_choice 
OR 
    Table1.id = Table2.third_choice 
GROUP BY 
    Table1.id,
    Table1.day
```

Refer to this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=eea27fe9364c0fe4b96a846c9441f723

Answer (score 1):

In those table structures, I normally use subquery instead of join.

```
SELECT
    a.day,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE first_choice = a.id) AS first_choice,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE second_choice = a.id) AS second_choice,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE third_choice = a.id) AS third_choice
FROM Table1 a
```